# SQL Query Select That User Don't Have The Products

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.3

Im trying to make a feature called "Edit Profile User" this

so in this feature im as Admin that can Edit User's Profile such as Name, username , DOB, etc.

in this feature we also can edit/Assign Product to this user. Example

User A have product : 
 1. Shampoo
 2. Soap
 3. Toothpick

and in server we've more than 3 product which are : Shampoo, Soap, Toothpick, Sponge, and Towel (5 items)

so the problem is : how to show the items that User have and automatically selected in select option, and also show the product that user didnt have / still available in server ?

so the example is : 
User A Product : 
 1. Shampoo (selected)
 2. Soap (selected)
 3. Toothpick (selected)
 4. Sponge
 5. Towel

im still confuse and no idea , already a week searching on google . 
and i use Chosen from harvest with multiple select

here's the source : https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

can anybody help me figure it out this problem ? im so stressed

*and this project based in Laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST">     
      <select name="items[]" class="form-control">
       <option value="Ketchup" selected>Ketchup</option>
       <option value="Mustard">Mustard</option>
     </select>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Then in process.php

```
$items = $_POST['items'];
foreach ($items as $item) {
 echo '$item' . <br>;
}
```

This will show the items you've selected

Comment: thank you, i forget that the option is based on databases . Which is theres 2 different model . User and product hmm. Maybe later ill show you the detail looks like its hard asking question without the real code and screenshoot, did you mind if i mention u later ??